# UWP Entity Framework queries freeze in Release Build (.Net Native Toolchain)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, uwp, entity-framework-core, .net-native

Developing my app, I have encountered a strange issue with building and publish in release mode. Entity Framework Core queries take 5x time to execute in comparison with debug mode. I have search about this issue but I haven't found any solution.

Issues appeared when I use

```
Data.Include (x => (SomeItem))
```

and also on other requests.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Used dependencies :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "MetroLog": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client": "2.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2",
    "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations": "1.2.0",
    "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls": "1.2.0",
    "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed": "2.0.0",
    "MvvmLightLibs": "5.4.0-alpha",
    "Template10": "1.1.12",
    "Unity": "3.5.1404",
    "Win2D.uwp": "1.20.0"

  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

Tried to add

```
 <UseDotNetNativeSharedAssemblyFrameworkPackage>false</UseDotNetNativeSharedAssemblyFrameworkPackage>
```

in main project property groups, but didn't help.

Seems that when I will try to upload to Windows Store, they will also compile with .NET Native ToolChain and app will freeze. Can someone help on issue please?

Comment: my understanding was there was a newer version of `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` on the nightly that was 5.3 in version that had much better performance.  1 caveat though VS 2017 RC is required to get it :(.   https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5570

Comment: Thanks , i will try this, but VS 2017 comes into Release Candidate and i'm not sure if i need to use it.

Comment: FYI: VS 2017 has hit RTM.